# Raw data acquisition with USB microphone

Tags: matlab, signal-processing, fft

I'm a senior grade student in mechanical engineering. I study on IET(Impulse excitation technique). I need to do a test setup to find Young's Modulus, Shear Modulus and Poission ratio with this technique. The product link is given below that I would like to build. In this methot,after fixing metal on nodes points,it is hit by hammer.Then sound is recorded and processed. I built a prototype of this product but I'm using a low grade microphone(approx. 10 dollar). I use a simple FFT method to find the frequency.

https://www.imce.eu/products/rfda-basic

Here is my questions. I need to find the frequency of the metal sample to calculate coefficients mentioned above. I detected frequency value with simple matlab code. Could these be correct values? Can the filters in the sound card inside my computer change these values? I have found usb microphones that can measure between 50Hz-50khz and these values match the range of values written in standards(ASTM-1876 - IET standard). Just changing my microfone will help me get the right result? Could I get the raw sound data with USB microphone? Or do I need to use DAQ card and compatible microphone.

I hope I can explain these in good way.
If you have any experience about it, I would be glad to share it with me.

*Thanks for helping.*

Comment: I don't think this is really on topic here but I have seen one of these working with a bog standard usb microscope. Get a standard piece (known modulus, weight, dimensions) to test your system out.

Comment: install an app or google for `Online Tone Generator` to generate a known frequency to confirm your measuring technique also indicate same freq ... also this site might be a better match for these questions https://sound.stackexchange.com/    here on SO it focuses on programming questions not so much project design ... sound like a cool project ...  have fun  !

Comment: Sorry about to wrong topic place. I'm new in this platform. Actually I'm really confused about this project so I can ask these questions. When I do fft analysis of the sound data , I see a lot of peak values at different frequency, how can I find which one is the correct frequency. I pick to analyse high amplitute one. Is this always correct or should I implement different techniques to determine the main voice frequency?